# Routing mail from domain to external provider

Tags: domain-name-system, sendmail, g-suite

I have a server with hostname and DNS `example.com`. I also have a google apps account for `user@example.com`. I have my MX records setup correctly and I can send and receive emails to and from `user@example.com` with my personal email.

On server `example.com`, I have some code sending email using sendmail to `admin@example.com`. I don't have any smtp configured with sendmail. I can send mail from server `example.com` to `user@otherdomain.com`, but when I try to send an email from server `example.com` to `admin@example.com` I get the following error in `/var/log/maillog`:

```
... while talking to [127.0.0.1]:
>>> DATA
<<< 550 5.1.1 <user@example.com>... User unknown
550 5.1.1 <user@example.com>... User unknown
<<< 503 5.0.0 Need RCPT (recipient)
```

I imagine this is because sendmail is receiving the email to `user@example.com`, and going "ah-ha! **I'm** example.com! I just need to send it to the user on this server." rather than looking at the MX records and seeing it needs to forward them to the gmail servers.

How can I tell sendmail to forward all messages off to the gmail servers irrespective of the domain?

Note: domains changed to `example.com` to protect the innocent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is - as you deduced - that your server's hostname is `example.com` making the MTA on that server think that any e-mail messages to `@example.com` should be delivered locally.

The quick solution is to simply change the hostname, e.g. call your server `www.example.com`.

Alternatively you use sendmail's MAIL_HUB feature to redirect local mail to another server: in the sendmail.mc macro file set:

```
define(`MAIL_HUB', `mailer:servername')
```

With that servername replaced by the hostname of your primary MX record. That will redirect messages send from your server to `<username>@<hostname>` i.e. `drew@example.com` to servername.

The actual answer to the question: *"How can I tell sendmail to forward all messages off to the gmail servers irrespective of the domain?"* is: 
You don't want that. Gmail is not an open relay and will reject anything that's not handled locally.

The feature does exist and is called a SMART_HOST in sendmail jargon. That requires an outgoing smtp server specifically configured to relay for your ip-address (range) such as the outgoing SMTP server of your ISP.

```
define(`SMART_HOST', `smtp.your.provider')dnl
```

Comment: Sorry, I should clarify that questoin. If google is handling my MX records, how do I tell sendmail to deliver messages @example.com at my google servers. That is, sendmail does its normal delivery thing and finds the gmail servers through the MX records as it would or any other domain which is not example.com.

Comment: I ended up changing the hostname, but was still hoping to understand the problem a bit deeper

Comment: When I do this ALL email gets sent to the gmail. Even server emails from cron. I am not quite looking to do that. Anyway around this?

Answer (score 3):

1. Name the host `hostname.example.com` (as reported by `hostname --fqdn`).
   The procedure is OS/distribution dependent.
2. If `example.com` remains on list of local email domains then turn off auto-configuration of local email domains list.

Checking list of local email domains:
As root execute

```
echo $=w | sendmail -bt
```

Removing auto-configuration of local email domains list:
In sendmail.mc add the following line, recompile sendmail.cf and restart/reload sendmail daemon

```
define(`confDONT_PROBE_INTERFACES',`True')
```

Local email domains may be explicitly listed in `/etc/mail/local-host-names`.

Comment: Thank you so much.... define(`confDONT_PROBE_INTERFACES',`True')   worked great. Why and how does this work?